# passing #foo selectors into $.get() data URL parameters

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an ajax call using $.get() where I want to pass in a specific element selector (#id) into the data:

```
$.get('http://www.url.com',
    {
     param1: 'param1Val',
     param2: 'param2Val',
     #id:    'selector'
     }
     function(data) {
        ...
     });
```

I could try passing it in as

```
$.get('http://www.url.com#id', ... );
```

**EDIT**
The purpose of attempting to use a #selector within the request URL is to grab only a specific "chunk" of HTML from within a specified element -- hence, I use remote_URL#element_id in the address. This works the same as any `<a href="#go_to_element">Go to element with id="go_to_element"</a>` link which will send you to a specific part of the page.

See the answer below.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? (other than you should put `#id` into a string). `{'#id': 'selector'}` should be fine. Or I don't get your question. What is the result you want to get? What do you want to do with the selector?

Comment: you want the value of #id to be passed with the data?

Comment: It doesn't matter what he's trying to do with the selector if he's trying to $.get() to another domain without using JSONP.  It won't work anyway.

Comment: @kasdega makes a good point. If you're intending this to be cross-domain you'll have to use a proxy or JSONP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's $.load() method allows you to send an AJAX request to a specific section of another page, returning the HTML contents of that section in the data parameter in the $.load method's callback function.

http://api.jquery.com/load/ (Re: Load Page Fragments)

```
$.load('www.localurl.com#container',
    function(data) {
        // do something
    });
```

Thanks to those who attempted to help on this! Sorry the question was poorly phrased.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to pass "#id" as a query string paramter then you'll have to wrap it in quotes.  Also, you're missing a comma after your second parameter.  The function call you're looking for should be written as:

```
$.get('/mypage.php',   // local page
    {
        param1: 'param1Val',
        param2: 'param2Val',
        '#id':  'selector'
    },
    function(data) {
        // do something here...
    }
);
```

Comment: Please note that you can not make cross domain calls with javascript unless you're using JSONP which has to be supported by the domain you're calling, or some browsers will allow a POST but still won't return any external data